# How do I NOT update a displayed image when it is changed on the backend?

Tags: html, image, caching

I'm looking for a way for my website to not change the image displayed to the user when the image is changed on the backend (assuming they do not refresh the page). Is there an easy way to do this?

Context/more detail:

I'm designing a plotting utility to be used by students which should display an image made based on their entered data (through a form fed to a PHP script).

However, they may be using this tool simultaneously, and if another student makes a plot, the first student's plot will be overwritten, even if they don't refresh the page.

I would like to make this not occur, so students can "keep" their plots. But, all my searching yields ways to force a refresh, not to force NOT refreshing.

The page in question is HTML (mostly a PHP script that takes their data inputs from a form and makes an image of it, and then the image tag).

Is there some sort of standard solution that I (as a non-web-developer) could easily implement?

(Also, since they are repeatedly making plots, I would prefer to do this without caching their old plots.)

Comment: The actual tool is available here, if that'd be helpful: http://phylabs1.physics.sunysb.edu/~physlab/PlottingTool/PHY120sPythonPlottingTool.html